# Javascript Project: Third select menu not updating?

Tags: javascript

I'm in the final stages of my project/homework, and I came across a little problem. My homework was to create three dynamically generated drop-down menus; however the third menu is not updating based on the choices of the second menu, rather it is creating another menu. The second menu updates correctly based on the choices of the first menu. Can someone tell me what's wrong? There is a JSFiddle demo in the comments. Thank you all!

Comment: Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3d6jb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not removing div with id="heroes" before you create another one. Your call to removeSiblings(x); does not remove div#heroes because div#heroes is not a sibling of select#myTeams. For div#heroes to be a sibling of select#myTeams you have to append it to div#teams instead of to div#stepOne. You would have to change line 108 of your fiddle:

```
document.getElementById('team').appendChild(heroDiv);
```

This will fix your issue with updating the third menu by selecting in the second, but you will have a similar issue with the form that renders when the user selects from the third menu.

Comment: holy moly, thank you! I fixed the problem with the forms also! :D

Comment: To follow the pattern you're using throughout, in the makeForm(t) function you could call removeSiblings(t); and when you add #formDiv to the dom, you should append it to #heroes instead of to #stepOne: document.getElementById('heroes').appendChild(formDiv);